# Build aosp davinci failed

Tags: android-source, android-build

I tried command "lunch aosp_davinci-userdebug"  but got the same error.

what should i do?

```
In file included from build/make/core/config.mk:353:
In file included from build/make/core/envsetup.mk:352:
In file included from build/make/target/product/telephony_vendor.mk:21:
device/xiaomi/davinci/device.mk:477: error:  vendor/xiaomi/davinci/davinci-vendor.mk does not exist..
11:38:03 dumpvars failed with: exit status 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question does not seem to be fit for this part of SE and may be removed by others due to it being offtopic. Please instead try reposing your question somewhere else such as [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), along with taking a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your vendor/xiaomi/davinci/davinci-vendor.mk  exists.